# What does [, mean in a JavaScript method signature?

Tags: javascript, json

I notice method signatures in JavaScript sometimes have multiple parameters like this:

`let json = JSON.stringify(value[, replacer, space])`

To me, it looks like this is a grammar that says replacer is an index for value, but this surely isn't the case. What does [, mean?

Comment: It means those parameters are optional.

Comment: That's just used in documentation, it's not actual JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I notice also in D3.js, usage like this: 

```dispatch.call(type[, that[, arguments…]])```. It looks nested - is it different in meaning?

Comment: No, it's the same. Just different styles.

Comment: @Barmar it could distinguish whether the two arguments can be omitted individually or only together. (But that would be wrong in this case)

Comment: The D3 style makes it clear that each parameter is optional. The MDN style could be interpreted as meaning that if you supply `replacer` you also have to supply `space`. But that's not actually true.

Comment: @Bergi It could be used that way, but MDN isn't doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more for documentation of function arguments, and not part of syntax of the language. It means everything inside the [] including the comma, is optional arguments. Sometimes even, the parameters without commas are in brackets like so

```js
someMethod(a, [b], [c])
```

But it's the same thing mostly.